# Limpiar área de trabajo de GIT persisistiendo los cambios sin subir al servidor

Tags: git, sourcetree

El proyecto en el que trabajo con mi equipo actualmente tiene muchos archivos de configuración en los que tengo que introducir el nombre del equipo local. Son como 9 archivos, y ver esos cambios en la lista de archivos modificados de git es un tanto molesto.

No quiero añadir estos archivos al gitignore porque si hay que añadir más parámetros de configuración el .gitignore ignoraría los nuevos cambios.

Mi pregunta es si hay posibilidad de hacer desaparecer los cambios de estos archivos pero aceptando cambios futuros. Una especie de commit que se quede sólo en mi ordenador local y no tenga por que subir al servidor.

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: ¿puedes separar cada uno de esos archivos en dos, uno que tenga la parte independiente del equipo local, y que haga un "include" por así decir, del otro? De este modo el principal estaría bajo control de versiones, pero el incluido sería local de cada cual y estaría en .gitignore

Comment: O quizás estés interesado en [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing), no sé si entendí bien la pregunta.

Comment: Con git stash pierdes los cambios actuales si los necesita en el proyecto no los tendra hasta que los aplique de nuevo no es una solución. @abulafia

Comment: @solamente No quise extenderme mucho hasta ver su respuesta, pero entiendo que podría tener las modificaciones locales sin "commitear", y cuando haya "actualizaciones" en esas configuraciones hacer el `stash`, traerse los cambios con `pull`, y luego aplicar el stash para recuperar sus modificaciones locales. Aunque no lo veo muy práctico, no.

Comment: Realmente la solución sería por crear durante el *build* un paso que obtuviera los valores necesarios, preguntando al sistema su nombre, por ejemplo

Comment: No... un stash hace que pierda los cambios... por lo que no me serviría... pero muchas gracias por comentar! La idea que ha dado abulafia es buena... hacer una especie de Include del archivo que esté fuera del area de trabajo... Tendría que estudiar esa propuesta. Gracias!

Comment: Si.. lo del build es algo como hace jenkins... ¿Verdad? Que a la hora de hacer el build y posteriormente el despliegue implementa sus configuraciones

Comment: Podrias poner tus archivos de configuracion con otro nombre, por ejemplo si se llama `config.ini`, hacer una copia con el nombre `config.sample.ini` de esa forma agregas al .gitignore el `config.ini` y la configuracion por defecto quedara en `config.sample.ini`. Cuando alguien clone el repositorio solo tendra que renombrar config.sample.ini a config.ini y hacer los cambios de configuracion en su propio entorno

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de archivos de configuración son? XML, json, makefile..., txt ?

Comment: @B1ON1C yo te recomiendo usar patchfiles https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432671/pasar-un-solo-archivo-de-una-rama-a-la-principal-en-git/432767#432767