# Pasar un solo archivo de una rama a la principal en Git

Tags: git, archivo, git-merge

soy nuevo en el tema de Git así que disculpad si digo muchas burradas.

Yo inicio un repositorio en la rama master con las carpetas y archivos que ya tienen código.
Posteriormente creo la rama develop y modifico una serie de archivos realizando finalmente un commit.
Sigo trabajando y me doy cuenta de que uno de los archivos modificados ya está bien y quiero pasarlo a la rama master para que "sobrescriba" el que allí está pero dejar el resto en la develop para seguir trabajando en ellos.

¿Se puede pasar un solo, o llegado elegir los archivos que que se pasan a la master?

Estoy usando Sourcetree. Ya se que existen comandos, pero soy más de interfaz, aunque obviamente con el tiempo seguro que aprendo los comandos.

Gracias.

Comment: Estando en `master`: `git checkout develop ruta/al/archivo.py`

Comment: @ffflabs deberias escribirlo como respuesta... con gusto le haría un upvote. Ahora bien, un comentario: esta no es la forma correcta de hacer control de versiones.... ejemplo sencillo. Agarras tu archivo, lo llevas a master, le haces commit. Luego modificas de nuevo el archivo en tu rama justo sobre algunas de las lineas que habias modificado previamente... cambios que al usar ramas normalmente no generarian conflictos, luego terminaste todo (por fin) y vas a hacer un merge a master.... BOOM! Conflicto. Git no va a poder saber si esas lineas tienen que estar como en una rama o la otra.

Comment: @eftshift0: Sin duda. Lo que yo sugeriría es commitear únicamente el archivo en cuestión y desde master hacer un `git cherry-pick` a ese SHA. Pero el OP preguntó cómo pisar el archivo. Además ¿Quien no ha pisado el `.gitignore`  de master con el de develop? Yo muchas veces

Comment: Mi comentario no era una crítica a tu respuesta. Muy por el contrario, por eso te dije que le haría upvote, eso es lo que pidió el OP asi que muy bien! (en serio, haz la respuesta). Mi comentario es más bien hacia la forma en la que el OP quiere trabajar.

Comment: otra forma en la que esta forma de trabajo te va a morder es si el archivo se modifica en ambas ramas. Al hacer el checkout indicando que se traiga el archivo de la otra rama, los cambios que se hicieron en _esta_ rama, se pierden. Asi que, mensaje para SideTest: **no deberías utilizar esta forma de trabajo**.

Comment: ah... y bienvenido a SO!

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos. Aunque la verdad es que me quedo más o menos igual. En resumen que lo que quiero hacer en parte no se puede y en parte es una mala práctica. De acuerdo. Entonces, ¿Cómo se haría?, ¿Debo tomar ese archivo realizar un commit solo para el y posteriormente unificar ese commit en la rama master? Lo que sí me queda claro es que tendré que mirarme muy bien los flujos de trabajo con Git.

Comment: Por cierto, @SideTest yo tampoco me he visto forzado a usar los comandos de consola, pero como verás en mi respuesta es algo de lo que no siempre vamos a poder escapar. Por lo anterior te recomiendo probarlo con otro repo que hagas en tu local antes de probarlo en serio ya que como dije... no tengo experiencia usando git con comandos... y si bien entiendo la lógica si algo sale mal no podría ayudarte después

Comment: En general creo que la respuesta correcta es que tienes que aprender que las revisions no se hacen por archivos sino por cambios que _en su conjunto_ (incluso si son varios archivos) generan una nueva version del proyecto que te gustaria guardar. Si estas trabajando diferentes cosas (digamos, features) al mismo tiempo, la recomendacion es separar cada cosa en una rama diferente y luego usar tecnicas de merge/rebase para aplicar dichos cambios (como ramas o revisions) en donde se necesite.... continua

Comment: Tratar de manejar cambios sobre los archivos "a pie" (con checkout de archivos o con diff) tiene sus casos de uso para situaciones _muy puntuales_. No las recomendaria para usarlas con git _a menos que sepas lo que estas haciendo_ (a veces hay que usarlas, no digo lo contrario... pero quiero recalcar el **a veces**).

Comment: ... y la consola es donde esta el poder. :-)

Comment: ¡Gracias a todos por vuestras opiniones y consejos!

Answer (score 2):

Pasando lo que dijiste a un estado inicial asumiremos que hiciste lo siguiente en un repo nuevo

```
git commit -m "las carpetas y archivos que ya tienen código"
git checkout -b develop
git commit -m "modifico una serie de archivos"
```

Esto nos dará un árbol que se ve así:

[image: estado inicial de la pregunta]

Ahora tienes uno de los archivos listo para hacerle commit, pero no quieres arruinarlo, porque solo necesitas ese archivo, pero el commit anterior tiene más archivos de los que necesitas y solo necesitas uno...

ciertamente debe de hacer algunas maneras de hacerlo, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

1. creo un patchfile (`patchfile1`) para el archivo que tiene las modificaciones que quiero
2. creo un patchfile (`patchfile2`) para los demás archivos que voy a trabajar después
3. me paso a master

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
4. creo un nuevo brazo para agregar los cambios al archivo que quiero

   ```
   git checkout -b develop1
   ```
5. resturo el `patchfile1`
6. le hago commit

   ```
   git commit -m "modificaciones a archivo"
   ```
7. me paso a master de nuevo

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
8. creo un brazo para el resto de los archivos (`develop2`)

   ```
   git checkout -b develop2
   ```
9. resturo el `patchfile2`
10. le hago commit

    ```
    git commit -m "mis demás archivos que voy a trabajar juntos"
    ```
11. como de aquí ya todo tiene sentido borramos develop

    ```
    git branch -d develop
    ```

[image: visualización de paso 11]

12. integramos el cambio de `develop1` con master

    ```
    git checkout master
    git merge develop1
    ```
13. ya podemos borrar `develop1`

    ```
    git branch -d develop1
    ```
14. renombramos `develop2` para que se llame `develop` y nunca nadie lo sabrá

Para el paso 14 creo que se puede hacer con un solo comando:

```
git branch -m develop2 develop
```

pero si no fuera el caso

```
git checkout develop2
git checkout -b develop
git branch -d develop2
git push origin develop
```

---

Sé que a mas de uno no podría gustarle esa primera respuesta por ser muy mañosa, así que idealmente deberías de hacerlo con squash, que hasta donde yo me quedé solo github lo soportaba.

Básicamente se trata de

```
git checkout master
git checkout develop
git checkout -b develop1
git commit -m "modificaciones a archivo"
git commit -m "borro los archivos que no necesito"
git reset --soft master
git add . && git commit -m "agregando solo un archivo"
```

y luego a subimos cambios

```
git checkout master
git merge develop1
git pull
git push origin master
```

de manera que los commits y sus mensajes se pierden y solo queda un commit que aparentemente salió dela nada y estás juntando todos los commits en uno y esto se vería así:

[image: estado final con squash]

Comment: Creo que es mucho mas sencillo y directo lo que recomienda @ffflabs en los comentarios a la pregunta. En todo caso, queria comentar que `git merge` tiene una opcion de squash: `git merge --squash`. Yo soy muy dado a usar `git reset --soft`, ciertamente (`git reset --soft` es **la lo cu ra**)... pero el `merge --squash` tiene sus usos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan extensa explicación. Miraré de ponerla en práctica aunque esto está bastante por encima de mi actual nivel. La primera parte, así lo hice y lo del patchfile lo había leído, pero sin llegar a convencerme (seguramente porque no tengo los conocimientos apropiados). De todas formas veo que mi planteamiento no es correcto para la forma de trabajar con Git. De lo contrario habría un proceso más sencillo. Probaré también lo que comenta @ffflabs. A parte de eso, ¿Qué programa usas para ver  así la interfaz de las ramas? Me parece muy interesante.